# Поиск подстроки в строке начиная сначала

Tags: android

На форме есть EditText и ListView. Есть коллекция состоящая из строк, а также есть коллекция tmpArr, которая через адаптер будет выводиться в ListView. Но прежде чем вывести ее в ListView нужно проверить содержится ли вводимое в EditText слово в строке из коллекции и если содержится добавить слово из первой коллекции в коллекцию tmpArr. Причем нужно проверять содержится ли начиная с первого символа. contains не подходит. Делаю так

```html
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        txtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                tmpArr.clear();
                for (String s : rusArr) {
                    int txtSearchLenght = charSequence.length();
                    String str = s.substring(0, txtSearchLenght);
                    if (charSequence.equals(str)) {
                        tmpArr.add(s);
                    }
                }
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tmpArr);
                list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Но когда начинаю вводить второй символ в EditText программа вылетает. Вот стектрейс

```html
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; regionStart=0; regionLength=2
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
at ru.mysite.project1.MainActivity$1.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:136)
at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8186)
at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:8248)
at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:10370)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1208)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:578)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:509)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:508)
at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:844)
at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:198)
at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:183)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:345)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:91)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прежде чем резать случайную строку надо бы длину проверять.
А в Вашем случае проще использовать `String.startsWith()`:

```
        String tmp = charSequence.toString();
        for (String s : rusArr) {
            if (s.startsWith(tmp)) {
                tmpArr.add(s);
            }
        }
```

Comment: не догадался использовать startsWith. Спасибо.